# Can not find locator protractor

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor, e2e-testing

I have a problem. In app.e2e-spec.ts, it moves me to the login page. There are methods in the file,
which it calls. When you click on the SignIn button it returns the title of the dashboard page. As if login failed. However, he gets the message:

```
should be able to login
- Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 11 seconds. This may be because the current page is not an Angular application. Please see the FAQ for more details: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular
While waiting for element with locator - Locator: By(css selector, h2)
```

On this page the element looks like this:

```
<h2 _ngcontent-c5 = ""> Dashboard API </h2>
```

app.e2e-spec.ts

```
it('should show login page', () => {
page.navigateToHome();
page.maximizeWindow();
expect(page.getLoginBoxTitle()).toEqual('Sign In');
});

it('should be able to login', () => {
page.navigateToHome();
page.login();
expect(page.getPageTitle()).toEqual('Dashboard API');
page.navigateToDashboard();
});
```

app.po.ts

```
login() {
element(by.name('username')).sendKeys('test@test.en');
element(by.name('password')).sendKeys('test123');
element(by.buttonText('SignIn')).click();
}

loginIfNotLoggedIn() {
if (element.all(by.css('.login-box')).length > 0) {
  this.login();
} else {
  console.info('Already logged in');
 }
}

getLoginBoxTitle() {
 return element(by.css('h2')).getText();
}

getPageTitle() {
return element
  .all(by.css('h2'))
  .last()
  .getText();
}
```

dashboard.e2e-spec.ts

```
it('should get api status', () => {
 login.browserSleep();
 page.navigateToDashboard();
 login.loginIfNotLoggedIn();
 page.getStatusAPI();
 page.navigateToApplications();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After protractor 5 and angular 2/4, the async behavour is changed in protractor.

You need to use `async` ans `await` form to tell angular to wait until angular load into the browser before you start your testing

```
async login(name: string, pwd: string) {
    await this.username.sendKeys(name);
    await this.password.sendKeys(pwd);
    await this.loginButton.click();
    return browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.not(protractor.ExpectedConditions.urlContains('returnUrl')));
}
```

And then while calling the login method, you should say `await login()`